# Telethon Issue: OperationalError: database is locked

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, telethon

The issue was appearing because we're connecting the client twice in the code.

```
client = TelegramClient(phone, api_id, api_hash)

client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone)
    client.sign_in(phone, input('Enter the code: '))
```

Comment: The right way to do this is to answer your own question, not adding the answer to the question itself. ;)

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: sorry for that and thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the "DataBase is locked" error,

you'll have to restart/abort the kernal and then remove the already created session from your local directory. Remove the client.connect() line from the code as it's getting connected at the first line itself.

The session file must be created with the following name as {phone}.session in the directory where your python code is kept.

Answer (score 0):

You saved my day. I was facing the same issue, then I removed the client.start() and kept only the connect() part. That solved the issue. Kudos to you!